# What is the origin of the word "filtration" in measure theory.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, math-history, filtrations

What is the origin of the word *filtration* in measure theory?
What is the mental image that motivated this wording? What inspired this wording outside of the mathematical world?

Comment: My guess would be that it comes from the idea of filtering a signal from noise, but I don't have anything to back that up.

Comment: How about a reference where the term "filtration" is used in measure theory (as opposed to probability theory).

Comment: Does this answer the question ? [https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0622](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0622).